# Generating RDF From Natural Language

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, rdf, semantic-web, ontology

Are there any tools available for generating RDF from natural language? A [list of RDFizers](http://simile.mit.edu/wiki/RDFizers) compiled by the SIMILE project only mentions one, the Monrai Cypher. Unfortunately, it seems to have been a proprietary tool developed by Monrai Technologies, which has since disappeared, and I can't find any download links. Has anyone seen anything similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want some ontology learning and population tools.

[This online article](http://ontogenesis.knowledgeblog.org/331) lists 4 different systems:

- Text2Onto,
- Abraxas,
- KnowItAll,
- OntoLearn

You may want to check out the book; it reviews several ontology learning tools as well:
*Ontology learning from text: methods, evaluation and applications*, by Paul Buitelaar, Philipp Cimiano, Bernardo Magnini

Comment: the article seems to no longer be available

Comment: The article is available on web archive.  http://web.archive.org/web/20190304001759/http://ontogenesis.knowledgeblog.org/331

Answer (score 1):

You might look into [OpenCalias](http://www.opencalais.com/), [Zemanta](http://www.zemanta.com/api/) and [Hakia](http://blog.hakia.com/?p=312) which all have nice APIs for extracting semantic data out of internet resources. Not familiar with Monrai Cypher, but possibly these might help.

Comment: These look interesting, although it's unfortunate they all appear to be proprietary (albeit free) web services, and not downloadable code.

Comment: These generally tend to not be open-source because they heavily rely on named entity recognition to determine the subject and the object of the triple and that knowledge base takes a lot of expert man hours if you want it to be good.

Comment: My interest is in learning how they work. The only thing I'll learn from buying a black-box solution or service is how to waste my money.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the python [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/) 
to parse the text and emit the rdf tripplets